# Need help about web3.js and json rpc

Tags: web3.js, phantom, jsonrpc-api, phantom-wallet, sollet.io

[image]

Hello, I am trying to build a wallet using react native. I already completed Ethereum integration with web3 browser but I don't know how to do it with Solana?

How do solana wallets inject javascript into window and how they handle user requests?

Answer (score 1):

For integrating support for Solana, you can use `@solana-labs/wallet-adapter` library -- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter.

Quickstart docs -- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md